# Check variable every 5 seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have very complicated mission. I have 2 project that contacts one of each other with TCP connection (listener and client). I want to check in the server program if I got message from the client in the last 5 seconds. The client program send message every 3 seconds automatically if he is connected to the server(The connect function by clicking on "Connect to server" button).

The advanced here is that I need the Server to do other things too so it must to be in thread.
I had an idea that the server contains thread that start when the client send the FIRST message. When the thread start it start the timer every 5 seconds it check a variable that increase every 5 seconds OR every get message(And when I get message I stop the timer and start him from the beginning again).

I tried to do it but without success. I will add my code but it doesn't work. If anyone have an idea I would be very happy I tried for hours to do it.

Code :

```
//Definition
private int radarPulseNumber;
private int counterTimer; // It the counter of the timer tick's
private bool ifItFirstPulse = true;
private System.Timers.Timer timerForPulse;
private Thread TimerCountRadarPulse;

// Start the thread 
TimerCountRadarPulse = new Thread(() => { ifHaveConnection(); });
TimerCountRadarPulse.Start();


 private void DrawForPulseMessage(object ls)
 {            
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (ifItFirstPulse)
        {
            ifItFirstPulse = false;
            // Create a timer with a 5 second interval.
            timerForPulse = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            timerForPulse.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timerForPulse.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            counterTimer++;
            timerForPulse.Stop();
            timerForPulse.Start();

        } 
        radarPulseNumber++; // It is the counter how much recieve message we got from the client

        lbl_Pulse.Content = "" + radarPulseNumber.ToString();
        ImageConnect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ImageDisconnect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }));
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    counterTimer++;
}

private void ifHaveConnection() // Actually it's the function that checks the tick's of timer vs the actually recieves.
{
    if (l.numOfPulseRecieves != radarPulseNumber) // l.numOfPulseRecives is an field in object who gets the number of recieve from client 
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            // Initiallized variables for reConnect to server.
            radarPulseNumber = 0;
            counterTimer = 0;

            ImageConnect.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ImageDisconnect.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work": please expand with details.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? You need to tell us what behavior you're expecting, and what behavior you're seeing. Have you added some logging so that you can tell if the timer actually fires? Do you know if messages are being received?

Comment: Okay, there's a lot of other stuff going on here, but it seems what you basically need an example of is a task that would normally complete in 5 seconds, unless it is reset by some external method call (which we can simulate by a delegate that gets called every 3 seconds with 50/50 probability). Would that be accurate?

Comment: Guys, Thank you but I solved it by myself. Instead all this long work, I just send 1 if there is connection and -1 if not. And if after 3 seconds we got -1 so the client is disconnected -- > which mean 6 seconds check and not 5.. but it doesn't really important. Thank's anyway. :)